# Can't change Integer to Double, and this cause my code to fail

Tags: java, logic, division

I'am trying to divide *x* by 9, and when *x* divided by 9 returns something bigger than 1, I proceed with my code. But what if x is 10? 10 divided by 9 returns 1,1 which means that you can only make one item and the 0,1 should be returned to you.

Example:
I have 64 of item **a** and try to create another item **b** which needs at least 9 of item **a** to create one item **b**. If we divide 64 by 9 it returns 7,1 which means that we can get a max of 7 item **b**. The 0,1 gives me 0.0 when i try to round it up with **Math.ceil()**.

Anyone know how I can get 0,1 of 64 / 9 and round it up to one?

This is what I've tried:

```
Integer getIronBlocks = ironIngots / 9;
Integer getGoldIngots = goldNuggets / 9;
double ironIngotLeft = Math.ceil(getIronBlocks);
double goldNuggetLeft = Math.ceil(getGoldIngots);
```

I already know the issue of this code, but don't know how to fix it. Lets say ironIngots = 64 and we divide it by 9 we get 7 not 7,1. Changing Integer getIronBlocks to Double getIronBlocks will raise an error by IntelliJ

Comment: Why are you using `Integer` instead of `int`? "*If we divide 64 by 9 it returns 7,1*" - This is not correct. `64 / 9` will return `7` since both `64` and `9` are `int`-values, thus the result will be an `int` as well.

Comment: `ironIngots / 9.0` will result in 7.111 is that what you need? (note the .0 after 9)

Comment: btw, please read this link, it can make ur question/answer much more understandable https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: double goldNuggetLeft = Math.ceil(goldNuggets / 9.0) ?

Comment: @JeroenHeier thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need use double to store the result and divide by double.

```
    int ironIngots = 10;
    double getIronBlocks = ironIngots / 9.0;
    System.out.println("result : "+ getIronBlocks); // ---> 1.111111
```

https://ideone.com/Yz4yBO

If you divide by an int the result is an int.

Comment: what this guy said ^

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by using Integer class, the decimals of the result are lost.

So what you end up doing is rounding up 0 which will give 0 as a result.

Use BigDecimal if you want accuracy in the operation. Or Double, but Double has binary operations issue with accuracy.

Comment: I see thank you i've solved the issue, it threw me an error due to me using Double instead of double....